# Inject JavaScript into webView.loadUrl

Tags: javascript, android

Is there some way to inject a JavaScript function into `webView` with a websites URL?

I have tried many different ways, but what I'm thinking is something like this

```java
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
webView.loadUrl("https://example.com/javascript:Android.getdate()")
```

`getdate()` being a function within my android app.

`onPageFinished` has code that reads a websites html as a string and I need to get the date to display within that string.

Comment: You can try without writing "Android". You can write `webView.loadUrl("https://example.com/javascript:getdate()")`

Comment: Tried but did not work, but thanks for tossing an idea I did not think of yet